# Liferay Asset Publisher: Cannot open Document

Tags: liferay

after adding a document by portlet 'Documents and media' im trying to open the document within asset publisher, which is not working and detail view is not shown.

After publishing a document is is displayed inside of asset publisher. The document is visible by anyone (Guest role).

The asset publisher display settings are configured to show full content (Asset link behaviour) but after click on document it is not opening the detail page. It is just refreshing the hole page.

My setup is linux x64 tomcat 7 and liferay set up by myself. But i've tried liferay tomcat bundle in different versions too. I did not hook the asset publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was i used java8. Liferay does not support java8, even if most is working with it.